# Problems with for loops for Tile Mapping in Python

Tags: python, pygame, tiles

I'm trying to generate a large tile map which is then going to be displayed on the screen. The map should be random, and only consists of two types of tiles at the moment.

However, what happens now is that each row of the Tile Map is overwritten with the first row from the heightmap, so that my map displays straight line columns of similar tiles when it displays.

I believe this is due to how I wrote my for loops, where it iterates through the entire heightmap, before even reaching the second list of tiles. Although due to the somewhat random element of tile choice that I *tried* to include, there should be at least some noise introduced to the map, but it seems like there isn't any.

Here is a link to a screenshot of what displays when I run my code.

```
 import pygame, random



class Map(object):

    MAPWIDTH = 64
    MAPHEIGHT = 48
    HEIGHTS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    def __init__(self):
        self.heightmap = [[random.choice(self.HEIGHTS) for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT)]
        self.Tiles = [['' for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT)]
        for rows in self.Tiles:
            for row in self.heightmap:
                i = 0

                for height in row:
                        # 100% water block
                        if height == 0:
                            rows[i] = 'WATER'
                        # 70% water block
                        if height == range(1, 3):
                            if random.randint(0, 9) == range(0, 6):
                                rows[i] = 'WATER'
                            else:
                                rows[i] = 'GRASS'
                        # 50% water block
                        if height == 4:
                            if random.random() == 0:
                                rows[i] = 'WATER'
                            else:
                                rows[i] = 'GRASS'
                        # 80% grass block
                        if height == range(5, 7):
                            if random.randint(0, 9) == range(0, 6):
                                rows[i] = 'GRASS'
                            else:
                                rows[i] = 'WATER'
                        # 100% grass block
                        if height == 8:
                            rows[i] = 'GRASS'
                        i += 1
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zboQK.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write a lot of lines like:

```
if height == range(1, 3):
```

but that does not do what you think it does.

`range(1, 3)` returns the list `[1, 2]` (or an iterable that yields `1` and `2` if you're using python3), and that is never equal to a single integer.

---

You probably want to use a pattern like:

```
if height == 1 or height == 2
```

or

```
if 1 <= height <= 2:
```

or

```
if height in range(1, 2):
```

---

Nonetheless, you could simplify your code by creating a helper function that returns the chance of a grass tile for a given height:

```
def chance_of_grass(height):
    if   height == 0: return  0
    elif height <= 3: return 30
    elif height <= 4: return 50
    elif height <= 7: return 80

    return 100
```

and call that in your loop:

```
 def __init__(self):
    self.heightmap = [[random.choice(self.HEIGHTS) for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT)]
    self.Tiles = [['' for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT)]

    r_i = 0 # index of row
    for h_row in self.heightmap:
        c_i = 0 # index of column
        for height in row:
            is_grass = change_of_grass(height) >= random.randint(1, 100)
            self.Tiles[r_i][c_i] = 'GRASS' if is_grass else 'WATER'
            c_i += 1
        r_i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for both letting me know where I was wrong and then giving me a more efficient solution anyway! One follow-up question I had was whether chance_of_grass was the preferred styling for python code?
That is to say, should I use underscores or maybe camelcase (chanceOfGrass) when writing python methods?

Comment: @PKJamoo In python you generally use underscores for functions. From the python style guide: *Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.*

Answer (score 0):

```
self.heightmap = [[random.choice(self.HEIGHTS) for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT)]
self.Tiles = [['' for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT)]
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with that ^ but try this:

```
self.heightmap=[]
self.Tiles=[]
q=[]
for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH):
    for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT): q.append(random.choice(self.HEIGHTS))
    self.heightmap.append(q)
    q=[]
for w in range(self.MAPWIDTH):
    for h in range(self.MAPHEIGHT): q.append('')
    self.Tiles.append(q)
    q=[]
for rows in self.Tiles:
    for row in self.heightmap:
        i = 0
        for height in row:
                rows.pop(i)
                # 100% water block
                if height == 0:
                    rows.insert(i,'WATER')
                # 70% water block
                if height in range(1, 3):
                    if random.randint(0, 9) in range(0, 6):
                        rows.insert(i,'WATER')
                    else:
                        rows.insert(i,'GRASS')
                # 50% water block
                if height == 4:
                    if random.random() > 0.5:
                        rows.insert(i,'WATER')
                    else:
                        rows.insert(i,'GRASS')
                # 80% grass block
                if height in range(5, 7):
                    if random.randint(0, 9) in range(0, 6):
                        rows.insert(i,'GRASS')
                    else:
                        rows.insert(i,'WATER')
                # 100% grass block
                if height == 8:
                    rows.insert(i,'GRASS')
                i += 1
```